# problem setting item to localstorage using an iteration

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have the following code to set items to localstorage and it is working fine except for the last item has array from the pervious item.

```
var catname;
var catArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cat'));
const catdata = [];
var funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < catArr.length; i++) {     
funcs[i] = function() {  
    
    const catid = catArr[i]['id'];
    const catname = catArr[i]['name'];
  
            $.ajax({
                  url : "sales/item_search_cat?cat="+catid,
                  data : "GET",
                  dataType : "json",
                 async:'false',
                  success : function(data){
                       for(var x in data){
                           catdata.push(data[x]);
                           localStorage.setItem(catname,JSON.stringify(catdata));
                        }
                  }

                 });  
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < catArr.length; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      
}
```

cat item from localstorage

```
[{"name":"Bevarages","id":"12"},{"name":"Desserts","id":"13"}]
```

array from server for id 12

```
[{"value":"2","label":"Life Chilli & Garlic Sauce","cost_price":"14.58","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"9556086012303","inventory":null},{"value":"3","label":"Life Tomato Sauce","cost_price":"12.00","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"9556086010507","inventory":null},{"value":"4","label":"Safa Tomato Ketchup","cost_price":"9.58","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"014796502211","inventory":null}]
```

array from server for id 13

```
[{"value":"6","label":"Dark Soy Sauce","cost_price":"25.00","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":null,"inventory":null},{"value":"5","label":"Maggi Oyster Sauce","cost_price":"23.29","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"9556001602008","inventory":null}]
```

my result

item name Bevarages

```
[{"value":"2","label":"Life Chilli & Garlic Sauce","cost_price":"14.58","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"9556086012303","inventory":null},{"value":"3","label":"Life Tomato Sauce","cost_price":"12.00","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"9556086010507","inventory":null},{"value":"4","label":"Safa Tomato Ketchup","cost_price":"9.58","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"014796502211","inventory":null}]
```

item name Desserts

```
[{"value":"2","label":"Life Chilli & Garlic Sauce","cost_price":"14.58","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"9556086012303","inventory":null},{"value":"3","label":"Life Tomato Sauce","cost_price":"12.00","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"9556086010507","inventory":null},{"value":"4","label":"Safa Tomato Ketchup","cost_price":"9.58","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"014796502211","inventory":null},{"value":"6","label":"Dark Soy Sauce","cost_price":"25.00","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":null,"inventory":null},{"value":"5","label":"Maggi Oyster Sauce","cost_price":"23.29","unit_type":"Piece","price":null,"tax":null,"item_number":"9556001602008","inventory":null}]
```

As you can see the Desserts item has array for id 12 included in it which I do not want as it should have only array for id 13. How to make sure it works as I require?

Comment: This has the same problem as your earlier question.

Comment: You need a separate `i` closure for each iteration, but they're all closing over the same scope of `i`.